# SSL on dokku+nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm trying to setup SSL on my app using dokku and nginx

according to  [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) I just need to a ssl folder inside my app holder (in my case /home/dokkue/my_app) and dokku will read all the certs and load it from there.

However I'm getting a "SSL connection error"

the logs from nginx at "/var/log/nginx" is blank

is there any step that I missed on adding SSL?

BTW: I'm using digitalocean ubuntu+dokku image

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the server.crt and server.key files to /home/dokku//tls directory (you may have to create it first)

It's looked up in the post-deploy hook of the built-in nginx-vhosts plugin: https://github.com/progrium/dokku/blob/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts/post-deploy

Comment: See the last section of the article - helped me add: https://www.hakobaito.co.uk/b/setting-up-lets-encrypt-on-dokku/